# Calling a spring batch external restart through java application

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have a requirement where i need to call my spring batch application externally and not use the by default spring batch admin UI.

This is the url which i am hitting

```
http://localhost:8080/sample-batch-app/jobs/sampleJob.json?jobParameters=filename=C:\\Users\\test\\Documents\\test1\\WIP\\test2\\sample\\cvs\\process\\08242016\\failure\\sample.csv,fileavailable=true,run_date=2016/09/05,external=true
```

Using the below code

```
String url = postUrl;
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
        String json ="sample";
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        logger.debug("==Json sent to microservice==== "+json);
        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(json, requestHeaders);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,String.class);

        logger.debug("RESTServiceUtils.executePost-->===========Ends"+response.getStatusCode());
        if(response.getStatusCode()!=null && !response.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)){
            logger.info("Response is::============" + response.getBody());
        }
```

But when i check the logs , all the // and \ in the url gets removed as a result the file is not getting processed.

The sample url i hit from postman api it works fine.

Kindly help.

Comment: Just to confirm, `postUrl` is the value set above?

Comment: the problem seems to be the \\ which are coming in the request parameters. Somehow the \\ gets removed which was creating a problem. The / seems to be working perfectly. Yes posturl is the value set above

Comment: Why are you specifying the parameters that way and not passing them in as the body of the post (so that escaping, etc are handled for you)?

Comment: I think as per the spring-batch-admin documentation, these values are to be passed as request parameters and not in the body..thats what i inferred from the documentation. Please correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: It uses Spring MVC, so I wouldn't expect you to need to do that kind of gymnastics...